# How can I get python3 file.close to release the file lock?

Tags: python, file-io

Python3 file.close is apparently not letting go of the file, so it can't be used by Win7 commands.

To wit:

```
import os, time
hfile = "Positions.htm"
hf = open(hfile, "w")
hf.write(str(buf))
hf.close
time.sleep(2) # give it enough time to do the close
os.system(hfile) # run the html file in the default browser
```

This results in an error message from Win7, saying that it cannot access the file because it is currently in use. However, it is easily accessed after the python program terminates.

Yes, I know that similar questions have been asked here, but I have not seen one that gave a general answer.

Comment: use `with` to open your files and you won't have issues like this, out of interest how are you opening hfile?

Answer (score 3):

You just forgot to call `close()`

```
hf.close   # wrong
hf.close() # right
```

You can see that `hm.close` just gives you a bound method without calling it:

```
>>> hm.close
<built-in method close of _io.TextIOWrapper object at 0x7ffe8ec74b40>
```

As Padriac Cunning ham pointed out, you don't need to do this if you just use `with` syntax:

```
with open(hfile, 'w') as hf:
    hf.write(str(buf))
# Automatically closed
```